# Conditional options on Selectize.js

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I have a select with 2 type of options: user and group. When user is selected it's ok, but when is selected a group I need to replace the selected item with the list of users that are in the group, using the group like an alias for a set of them.

**Example**: I have this list of option:

```
var options: [
            {text: 'Ironman', value: '1', type: 'user' },
            {text: 'Spiderman', value: '2', type: 'user' },
            {text: 'Black Widow', value: '3', type: 'user' },
            {text: 'Superhero', value: '4', type: 'group' }
        ]
```

When is selected 'Superhero', I need the list of 'Ironman', 'Spiderman' and 'Black Widow' replace the choice.
 I can't find a correct event to prevent the selection and replace it with the list of users, retrieved with AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.on('change', handler)` event](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_events) :

```
// When you create your selectize
var $select = $("#select_id").selectize({
    // Options here
});
var selectizeControl = $select[0].selectize;
```

---

Then you can access it

```
selectizeControl.on('change', function() {
    var value = selectize.getValue();
    // From here you get the value, and do whatever you need with it
    console.log(value);

    if (options[value]["type"] == 'group')
    {
        var tmp = 0;
        var users = "";
        // Here, do your ajax call to get your list from the value
        ajaxCall(value, function(list) {
            // I guess you'd have an array from your server
            for (var user in list)
            {
                if (tmp > 0)
                    users += ",";
                users += user;
                tmp++;
            }
            $('#select_id').val(users);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: In this way I get the value of the group element, how can replace it?

Comment: @MTS Have you tried doing something like `$('#select_id').val('Ironman, Spiderman, Black Widow');` in the `onChange` event ?

Comment: The problem is that i need to prevent the select event of a group and collect the user info by AJAX, based on group selected.

Comment: @MTS I have edited my post, is it something like that you actually need ?